# How to convert String to Struct (in Swift)

Tags: swift

I have a `struct` like,

```
struct LoginConstants {
  struct Selectors {
    let testa = "test1234"
  }
}
```

and a class like,

```
class Login: XCTestCase {
  override class func setUp () {
    // below constant will have a value like "LoginConstants"
    let localConstants = "\(String(describing: self))Constants"

  }
}
```

... so here I have a struct-name as a string format in `localConstants`.

My Question is how I can access the `LoginConstants` properties from the `localConstants` string?

NOTE:
I know I can access the `LoginConstants()` directly.
But I am planning to create a parent class where I can access this `***Constants` struct dynamically.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C has the ability to do this, but Swift does not. If you give a class an Objective-C name via the `@objc` attribute, you can use the Objective-C runtime functions to access it by name. However, this is not possible with a struct.

It's probably not the best way to go anyway. A better solution is to rethink what you are trying to do, and access the struct type directly rather than by name.